# TPoint software, INDAT command - Format 4 (ALTAZ)

Tags: radio-telescope

I am working (in fact, trying to work) with TPoint for improving a solar telescope pointing calibration (SST, in Casleo, AR) and stumbled on the input data for INDAT command. SST is a multibeam solar observation telescope with Alt-Az support.

INDAT Observation record Format 4 is described as follows on the documentation:

```
star "observed" Az/El (°,°)
telescope raw Az/El (°,°)
[up to 2 auxiliary readings]
```

And the sample file for an AltAz support is mmt.dat, whose heading and 1st observational data row are follows:

```
!
!  Sample data from the Multiple Mirror Telescope
!

MMT 1987 July 8
: ALTAZ
+31 41 19.6 1987 07 08 +15.0  734.5  2608.0 0.30

02 59 39.744 +03 53 41.15 -0.00082 -0.0743 B1950 03 01 32.220 +04 04 05.72 23 01
```

On the data rows, what would be the "column headers"?

MTIA,

Myrna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:)

Are you talking about the meaning of this fields?:

**02 59 39.744 +03 53 41.15 -0.00082 -0.0743 B1950 03 01 32.220 +04 04 05.72 23 01**

According to [https://sites.astro.caltech.edu/~srk/TP/Literature/Tpoint_SunWorks.pdf](https://sites.astro.caltech.edu/%7Esrk/TP/Literature/Tpoint_SunWorks.pdf), they seem to belong to **Observation record format 2** (pag. 18):

- star mean RA/Dec (h,m,s,◦,′,′′, $\mu_{\alpha}$,$\mu_{\delta}$,equinox)
- telescope raw RA/Dec (h,m,s,◦,′,′′)
- local apparent sidereal time (h,m)

If you mean this fields:

**+31 41 19.6 1987 07 08 +15.0  734.5  2608.0 0.30**

They seem to be the *run parameters* (pag. 18):

- latitude (◦,′,′′)
- UTC date (y,m,d)
- temperature (◦C)
- pressure (mB)
- height above sea level (metre, default determined from pressure)
- relative humidity (range 0–1, default 0.5)

Comment: Yes, Luis, the meaning of the fields :) Thank you.
Have a nice week!